# How to create a table in databricks with an R script?

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks

I perform a data extraction process with R in which I extract data from a table that is in a web portal, I need to access that table as a query and I have the option to do it from azure databricks, I would like to know how I can carry my script to databrick to be able to save it as a table and that it can be consulted

````
    library(rvest)
    library(purrr)
    library(dplyr)
    library(xml2)

    dplyr::
      
      tidy_node <- function(node){
        xml_find_all(node, ".//br") %>% xml_add_sibling("p", ", ")
        xml_find_all(node, ".//br") %>% xml_remove()
        return(node)
      }

    get_order_details <- function(url) {
      page <- url %>%
        read_html()
      additional_columns <- page %>% html_elements("#supplier .oc-span")
      table <- page %>%
        html_element(".sticky-enabled") %>%
        html_table() %>%
        dplyr::mutate(
          order_number = basename(url), .before = 1,
          Nombre = additional_columns[1] %>% html_text(),
          `Dirección Principal` = tidy_node(additional_columns[2]) %>% html_text(trim = T),
          `Teléfono (Del Trabajo)` = additional_columns[3] %>% html_text(),
          `Teléfono (Celular)` = additional_columns[4] %>% html_text()
        )
    }


    urls.colombia.compra.microsoft <- paste0(
      "https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=",
      0:11,
      "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Microsoft&date_to_=%20&date_from_="
    )

    base.colombia.compra.microsft <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.microsoft, ~ .x %>%
                                                     read_html() %>%
                                                     html_table())

    base.colombia.compra.microsft

    urls.colombia.compra.google <- paste0(
      "https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=",
      0:11,
      "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=IAD%20Software%20I%20-%20Google&date_to_=%20&date_from_="
    )

    base.colombia.compra.google <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.google, ~ .x %>%
                                                   read_html() %>%
                                                   html_table())

    base.colombia.compra.google

    urls.colombia.compra.nube <- paste0(
      "https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra?page=",
      0:11,
      "&number_order=&state=&entity=&tool=Nube%20Pública%20III&date_to_=%20&date_from_="
    )

    base.colombia.compra.nube <- purrr::map_df(urls.colombia.compra.nube, ~ .x %>%
                                                 read_html() %>%
                                                 html_table())

    base.colombia.compra.nube

    base.consolidada.colombia.compra <- data.table::rbindlist(list(
      base.colombia.compra.microsft,
      base.colombia.compra.google,
      base.colombia.compra.nube
    ), idcol = "id")

    base.consolidada.colombia.compra

    all_urls <- paste0("https://colombiacompra.gov.co/tienda-virtual-del-estado-colombiano/ordenes-compra/", base.consolidada.colombia.compra$`Orden de Compra`)

    new_res <- purrr::map_df(all_urls, get_order_details)

    new_res

    Base.articulos.colombia.compra <- new_res %>% filter(!is.na(No))

    Base.articulos.colombia.compra 
```
````

How can i solve it?

Comment: Save it as a table where? `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/sparkr/`

Comment: Yes!!! Thank u so much!!